# How to get correct array sum in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have the following `initialDataSet`

```
0: {ID: 1, Province/State: "", Country/Region: "Thailand", Lat: 15, Long: 101, …}
1: {ID: 2, Province/State: "", Country/Region: "Japan", Lat: 36, Long: 138, …}
2: {ID: 3, Province/State: "", Country/Region: "Singapore", Lat: 1.2833, Long: 103.8333, …}
...
```

Inside each of them We have:

```
0:
ID: 1
Province/State: ""
Country/Region: "Thailand"
Lat: 15
Long: 101
data: (62) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {
```

And inside each `data:` We have:

```
data: Array(62)
0: {date: "1/22/20", Confirmed: 2, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0}
1: {date: "1/23/20", Confirmed: 3, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0}
2: {date: "1/24/20", Confirmed: 5, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0}
```

And we need to get the `total sum of Deaths`

We did:

```js
const initialDataSet = [
{ID: 1, "Province/State": "", "Country/Region": "Thailand", Lat: 15, Long: 101, data : [  {date: "1/22/20", Confirmed: 2, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/23/20", Confirmed: 3, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/24/20", Confirmed: 5, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0}
]},
 {ID: 2, "Province/State": "", "Country/Region": "Japan", Lat: 36, Long: 138, data : [ {date: "1/22/20", Confirmed: 2, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/23/20", Confirmed: 3, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/24/20", Confirmed: 5, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0}
]},
 {ID: 3, "Province/State": "", "Country/Region": "Singapore", Lat: 1.2833, Long: 103.8333, data: [ {date: "1/22/20", Confirmed: 2, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/23/20", Confirmed: 3, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/24/20", Confirmed: 5, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0}
]}
];


var testTotals = [];
for (var d = 0; d < initialDataSet.length; d++) {
  var trackObj = initialDataSet[d];
  for (var c = 0; c < trackObj.data.length; c++) {
    testTotals.push(parseInt(trackObj.data[c].Deaths));
  }
}
var myTots = testTotals.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(myTots);
```

But console gives `NaN`

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this. That would really help to debug.

Comment: initialDataSet is an object  or is it an array?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan how do I find out?

Comment: Check the output of `console.log(testTotals.join())`

Comment: Examine your data and check to see if any of the statistics objects are missing a "Deaths" property. If just one of those exists, you'll end up with `NaN`.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it and add a relevant subset of your array

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging to determine where the problem is - it looks like it's in the `parseInt` part (giving at least one `NaN`) - is that because `trackObj.data[c]` isn't what you expect it to be?  Or is it that in one (or more) cases `Deaths` isn't a valid number?   Should be easy enough to find with some basic debugging.  Most likely it's your data set.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, trying to insert the data

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah thought it was easy too but :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the (big) [data set](http://jikupin.com/wp-content/themes/JikuHealth/scripts/data/global/3-24-20_covid-19_data.json) that you're working on, the following extra information could be extracted:

1. The time series are incremental, which means that the last value of the `data` array is the total number at that point in time; this reduces one inner loop
2. If the last value of the `data` array is an empty string, there's no positive integer preceding it, which means that you can just coerce that value by using `|| 0`

I've adjusted your data set to highlight those findings, and changed the solution accordingly.

```js
const initialDataSet = [
{ID: 1, "Province/State": "", "Country/Region": "Thailand", Lat: 15, Long: 101, data : [  {date: "1/22/20", Confirmed: 2, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/23/20", Confirmed: 3, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/24/20", Confirmed: 5, Deaths: '', Recovered: 0}
]},
 {ID: 2, "Province/State": "", "Country/Region": "Japan", Lat: 36, Long: 138, data : [ {date: "1/22/20", Confirmed: 2, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/23/20", Confirmed: 3, Deaths: 2, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/24/20", Confirmed: 5, Deaths: 3, Recovered: 0}
]},
 {ID: 3, "Province/State": "", "Country/Region": "Singapore", Lat: 1.2833, Long: 103.8333, data: [ {date: "1/22/20", Confirmed: 2, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/23/20", Confirmed: 3, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/24/20", Confirmed: 5, Deaths: '', Recovered: 0}
]}
];

const x = initialDataSet.reduce((total, {data}) => {
  const lastItem = data[data.length - 1]
  // it's unlikely, but possible that `data` is an empty array
  return lastItem ? total + (lastItem.Deaths || 0) : total
}, 0)
console.log(x);
```

Comment: what if we have one obj like `{date: "3/23/20", Confirmed: "", Deaths: "", Recovered: ""}` ?

Comment: @rob.m `"" || 0` would become `0` ... not sure if that's acceptable, but that's what it would do

Comment: testing but I get the wrong sum mind to come to chat and I show the full json?

Comment: @rob.m do you have a chat link?

Comment: invited you now

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the data is incremental, so you have to sum just the last ones.
You might do it with `reduce`.

And to handle **NaN**s, you might use `~~` (double binary not) which coerce values to integers.

```js
const initialDataSet = [
{ID: 1, "Province/State": "", "Country/Region": "Thailand", Lat: 15, Long: 101, data : [  
 {date: "1/22/20", Confirmed: 2, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/23/20", Confirmed: 3, Deaths: "", Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/24/20", Confirmed: 5, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0}
]},
 {ID: 2, "Province/State": "", "Country/Region": "Japan", Lat: 36, Long: 138, data : [
 {date: "1/22/20", Confirmed: 2, Deaths: 'none', Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/23/20", Confirmed: 3, Deaths: "0", Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/24/20", Confirmed: 5,              Recovered: 0}
]},
 {ID: 3, "Province/State": "", "Country/Region": "Singapore", Lat: 1.2833, Long: 103.8333, data: [
 {date: "1/22/20", Confirmed: 2, Deaths: 0, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/23/20", Confirmed: 3, Deaths: 1, Recovered: 0},
 {date: "1/24/20", Confirmed: 5, Deaths: "2", Recovered: 0}
]}
];


var deathsTotals = initialDataSet.reduce((t, {data}) => t + ~~data[data.length-1].Deaths, 0);
  
console.log(deathsTotals)
```

Comment: Thanks, tried but I get `194455000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000001200000000000000000600000800000930000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000612013743000011000000330000048000000200000000865000050008000030000000000000000000000000000000000000001001000`

Comment: testing but I get the wrong sum mind to come to chat and I show the full json?

Answer (score 1):

Add a simple test to your loop:

```
var testTotals = [];
for (var d = 0; d < initialDataSet.length; d++) {
  var trackObj = initialDataSet[d];
  for (var c = 0; c < trackObj.data.length; c++) {
    testTotals.push(parseInt(trackObj.data[c].Deaths || 0));
  }
}
var myTots = testTotals.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(myTots);
```

Note that unless you need the individual values as an array for other reasons, you could do all the math in the initial iteration.

Another thing you could do would be to explicitly convert the value to a number, and then only add the value if it isn't `NaN`:

```
var testTotals = [];
for (var d = 0; d < initialDataSet.length; d++) {
  var trackObj = initialDataSet[d];
  for (var c = 0; c < trackObj.data.length; c++) {
    let value = +trackObj.data[c].Deaths;
    if (!isNaN(value))
      testTotals.push(value);
  }
}
var myTots = testTotals.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(myTots);
```

That would also handle entries with `Deaths: "N/A"` or other non-numeric, non-empty strings.

Comment: I have noticed I have soem empty string, how would you check for null, empty string or undefined? Like this trackObj.data[c].Deaths != ""

Comment: @rob.m the technique in the answer Jack gave is probably better than mine here, where `|| 0` is added before each value is added to the array.

Comment: what if we have one obj like `{date: "3/23/20", Confirmed: "", Deaths: "", Recovered: ""}` ?

Comment: @rob.m the idea is to keep non-numeric values out of the array. That's what the `|| 0` code does. Now, if there are entries that have non-empty strings that are also not numbers, a different approach would be called for.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce with a nested approach.

```js
const
    initialDataSet = [{ ID: 1, "Province/State": "", "Country/Region": "Thailand", Lat: 15, Long: 101, data: [{ date: "1/22/20", Confirmed: 2, Deaths: '', Recovered: 0 }, { date: "1/23/20", Confirmed: 3, Deaths: 2, Recovered: 0 }, { date: "1/24/20", Confirmed: 5, Deaths: 3, Recovered: 0 }] }, { ID: 2, "Province/State": "", "Country/Region": "Japan", Lat: 36, Long: 138, data: [{ date: "1/22/20", Confirmed: 2, Deaths: 2, Recovered: 0 }, { date: "1/23/20", Confirmed: 3, Deaths: 4, Recovered: 0 }, { date: "1/24/20", Confirmed: 5, Deaths: 5, Recovered: 0 }] }, { ID: 3, "Province/State": "", "Country/Region": "Singapore", Lat: 1.2833, Long: 103.8333, data: [{ date: "1/22/20", Confirmed: 2, Deaths: 1, Recovered: 0 }, { date: "1/23/20", Confirmed: 3, Deaths: 2, Recovered: 0 }, { date: "1/24/20", Confirmed: 5, Deaths: 3, Recovered: 0 }] }]
    total = initialDataSet.reduce((sum, { data }) =>
        data.reduce((s, { Deaths }) => s + (Deaths || 0), sum), 0);

console.log(total);
```

Comment: what if we have one obj like `{date: "3/23/20", Confirmed: "", Deaths: "", Recovered: ""}` ?

Comment: then take a guarding value of zero.

Comment: thought you did here no? Deaths || 0

Comment: what? please see above.